Can't Shudras listen to the puranas?
I always thought that Shudras can read/listen to Puranas. But when reading Skanda Purana, came across one shocking verse:

23.The man conversant with Purāṇas should be an expert, clean, calm and devoid of malice.[1] He should be a good man, kind-hearted,
intelligent and fluent in speech. He should expound the meritorious
story.

When the expounder of the Purāṇas has occupied the seat of Vyāsa (i.e. the pulpit), he should not bow down to anyone till the portion
for the day or session is completed.

This learned expounder should not deliver his speech in a place infested with bad characters, Śūdras or beasts of prey, or in a
gambling house.


Skanda Purana II.iv.36


If we read the entire verse, it says to not expound divine knowledge in a place or around people unfit for spirituality. If a person born as Shudra wishing to acquire spiritual knowledge of the Brahman, a Guru will not reject him and consider him as an exception. However, he wouldn't do so in a large group of outcastes who're engaged in sinful acts such as drinking liquor, gambling, ill talks, etc.

Welcome back! ....

Please quote original Sanskrit verse. Translators often add their own interpretation.

I continued looking at the same Purana, similar verse is repeated in one more chapter however at the last chapter the following verse is there:

पुण्यं श्रुत्वा पुराणं वै दीर्घमा युश्च विंदति ॥ वेदविच्च भवेद्विप्रः
क्षत्रियो राज्यमाप्नुयात् ॥ १३ ॥
धनं धान्यं तथा वैश्यः शूद्रः सुखमवाप्नुयात् ॥ यः श्लोकपादं
शृणुयाद्विष्णुलोकं स गच्छति ॥ १४ ॥
Translation
People get long life by listening to this auspicious Purāṇa while a
king gets victory over the world with full domination of his enemies.
The Brāhmaṇas get learned in the Vedas while the Kṣatriyas get kingdom
by reading it. The Vaiśyas get the fortune of wealth and remain
gratified while its reading blesses the Śūdras with all happiness. By
listening to one chapter or just a śloka (i.e. verse) or half of a
śloka one goes to the abode of Viṣṇu.
Skanda Purana VIII.iii.44.13-14

So, the answer is that verse might be an interpolation.
